# Visual Studio Code Difficulty Installing AgML Dataset

Tags: python-3.x, git, github, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I am getting errors installing https://github.com/Project-AgML/AgML dataset.

Here is how to recreate the situation :

1. Open Visual Studio Code.
2. Create a folder in which we create two more folders: `workspace` and `work_env`.
   Here `work_env` is created by a Python virtual environment with python version `3.11.2`.
3. Create a hello-world `.ipynb` file, select interpreter to be the `python.exe` in `Scripts` of newly created `work_env`.
4. Click run. Visual Studio Code will ask you in install a package to make `ipynb` runnable.

Up to now everything works fine because basic commands like `hello world` indeed runs. Commands like `import numpy` or other packages will yield an error because `numpy` and other packages are yet to be installed in this virtual environment. This is totally expected.

On the other hand, git is newly downloaded and installed. Things should have been setup correctly in the sense that what's mentioned in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_23KUAEtUM can be carried out perfectly fine. Features like `git clone` and `git pull` and others function as expected.

Next, I type the following command in the first cell of my `ipynb` file:

```
!pip install -e git+https://github.com/Project-AgML/AgML.git@main#egg=agml
```

It takes 30 seconds to run and yields the long error:

```
Obtaining agml from git+https://github.com/Project-AgML/AgML.git@main#egg=agml
  Cloning https://github.com/Project-AgML/AgML.git (to revision main) to c:\users\r2d2w\...\work_env\src\agml
  Resolved https://github.com/Project-AgML/AgML.git to commit 086c0613e6d293c4ea263c7697b36a3ac4d2e311
Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/Project-AgML/AgML.git 'C:\Users\r2d2w\OneDrive\Desktop\McGill Sixth Semester (Winter 2023)\Machine Learning\project\work_env\src\agml'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\r2d2w\OneDrive\Desktop\McGill Sixth Semester (Winter 2023)\Machine Learning\project\work_env\src\agml\setup.py", line 22, in <module>
          long_description = f.read()
                             ^^^^^^^^
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 140: illegal multibyte sequence
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

And `import agml` will show that no module named `agml`.

If, instead of the main branch, I use:

```
!pip install -e git+https://github.com/Project-AgML/AgML.git#egg=agml
```

Then this single line runs for 20 minutes and still does not stop. I had to stop execution manually .

Finally, both commands will run successfully on google colab. They take at most 20 seconds to run .